# How avoid which the TIdHTTP component allocate all the file space at once when use Get?

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using `TIdHTTP.Get` to download a file. As parameter I'm passing a `TFileStream` object, I have noticed that when i execute the get method the file size is allocated at once before which the download was completed,   my question is `How I can avoid which the TIdHTTP component allocate all the file size in the disk at once when use Get?`

Comment: What would you like it to do when there isn't enough disk space? Fail 75% of the way through the download? That pre-allocation might be there for a reason.

Comment: @Warren - agree (I hate this e.g. in file managers), but imagine the opposite situation when you don't have enough space and meanwhile at downloading process you'll free some. And the [Content-Length](http://tinyurl.com/Content-Length) must not be included in the header, so the file size might be unknown in advance. I haven't checked how this situation is handled by Indy.

Comment: @daemon: The preallocation is an optimization, but it is not a requirment.  Indy's code does have a TODO item to make that feature customizable in the future, so it may happen eventually. `TIdHTTP` does already support `chunked` downloading when `Content-Length` is not present/used, in which case no pre-allocation would occur.

Comment: @Salvador - so the only way that come to my mind at this time is to use memory stream and save it to the file stream.

Comment: There is a simple alternative: derive a new class from `TFileStream` and override its `SetSize()` method to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As Remy said in his comment, if the response size is known in advance (from the [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) header member), Indy will always pre-allocate the entire stream size.

So the only workaround how to avoid the disk space allocation that came to my mind is to use the memory stream and copy the data from that stream into the file in progress.

The pre-allocation of the entire downloaded file size on disk is useful because even if you download a file into the memory stream then you'll still need to have enough space on your hard drive to save it anyway (and of course enough free memory for the download itself). A benefit of using memory stream is that you can get the time for freeing some disk space, but it depends a lot on what you are going to do.